# CSS issue not working in FireFox

Tags: c#, css, webforms

I have Repeater Control and in that i have code like this

```
<div runat="server" id="divleft" onmouseover="this.style.background='#BADFCE';"    onmouseout="this.style.background='white';">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCategory" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CategoryDescription")%>'
        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CourseLibraryCategoryID") %>' 
        OnClick="lnkCategory_Click"
        CssClass="courseLink">
    </asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:Label ID="lblCount" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Now i have to do that after `Click` on that `LinkButton` the background color of the div name 'divleft' has to be applied for that i code like this in .aspx.cs page......

```
 protected void lnkCategory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    LinkButton temp = (sender as LinkButton);
    temp.Attributes.Add("style", "color:green  !important;");
    (temp.NamingContainer.Controls[1] as System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl).Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:#BADFCE !important;");
 }
```

Now this code is perfectly running in IE and Chrome but not working in Firefox.

Comment: If the issues is on the client, show your client-side code, NOT your .net source code. We're debugging the HTML/CSS, not the ASP code.

Comment: Try using **firebug** and check which style it picking up

Comment: The same code is working perfectly in chrome and IE browser....

Comment: Also, "not working" is far too vague. What doesn't work, the color of the link, the background color of the div, the mouseover and mouseout event handlers, etc?

Comment: @KartikPatel: that is why you need to check in Firefox which style its picking up

Comment: When i check using Firebug it shows me<div id="ctl01_mainContent_ctl00_rptCategory_ctl04_divleft" style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% white;" onmouseout="this.style.background='white';" onmouseover="this.style.background='#BADFCE';">

Comment: yes thats after mouse out.....however first attribute temp.Attributes.Add("style", "color:green  !important;"); is working but background-color is not working...

Comment: I think that happens because the mouseout event resets the background color after you've set it. Try removing the `onmouseout` attribute from the div in the server side code. (Not sure why this would only happen on FF though; I don't have a C# compiler handy to test)

Comment: yes thats due to mouseout if i remove it then it works perfectly but now to do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use !important unless there is something wrong with your core CSS. If I were you, I would move the UI to a JavaScript layer.

jQuery:

```
jQuery('.courseLink').click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#divleft').css('background-color','#BADFCE');
    jQuery(this).css('color','green');
} );
```

Or Better Yet, something like this:

```
jQuery('.courseLink').click( function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('#divleft').addClass('active');
    jQuery(this).addClass('clicked');
} );
```

With (css):

```
#divleft.active {
    background-color:#BADFCE;
}
.courseLink.clicked {
    color:green;
}
```